# Decide whether $\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)^n$ is big O,Ω, or Θ of $\log(n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

So I have to find if $\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)^n$ is either big O, Ω or Θ of $log(n)$.My thinking went a bit like this: First of all, we can easily see that $\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)^n$ is strictly decreasing $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\forall x > 0$. $\log(x)$ is strictly increasing $\forall x > 0$. So eventually there will be a $k$ such that $\log(x) \geq \left(\frac{100}{101}\right)^n$ so $\left(\frac{100}{101}\right)^n = O(\log(x))$.

To be exact, if a proof was needed, I would let $h(x) = (\frac{100}{101})^n - log(x), \forall x > 0$.

Firstly, $h$ is stricly decreasing as $\forall x_1, x_2, x_1 < x_2 \rightarrow (\frac{100}{101})^{x_1} > (\frac{100}{101})^{x_2} \quad (1)$

$x_1 < x_2 \rightarrow log(x_1) < log(x_2) \rightarrow -log(x_1) > - log(x_2) \quad (2)$

From (1) and (2), $h$ is decreasing, and $$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}h(x) = - \infty, lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}h(x) = +\infty$$

Now let $a<b$, with $a$ infinitely close to $0^+$ and $b$ infinitely big, so close to $\infty$. Then $h(a) > 0, h(b) < 0$, and since $h$ is continuous  and $h(a)h(b)<0$, there will be a $x_0$ such that h(x_0) = 0 (intermediate value theorem). So, for $x_0 < x \rightarrow h(x_0) > h(x) \rightarrow h(x) < 0 \rightarrow (\frac{100}{101})^x < log(x)$. So there is a point $k > x_0$, with $C=1$, for which $(\frac{100}{101})^x = O(log(x))$

If that was my responce, would that be correct or not? Since I am not finding a exact value for $k$, but instead prove there exists one so big $O$ is satisfied. Also is there a easier way to prove such thing? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier approach.  You can simply notice that $h(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\log(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  Therefore $\frac{h(n)}{\log(n)} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, which implies in particular that $h(n) \leq \log(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$, so $h(n) = O(\log(n))$.